# get a dynamically loaded script to run once the dom is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a database field called "opposing_team_boxscore" that contains this javascript widget:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://widgets.sports-reference.com/wg.fcgi?css=1&site=br&url=%2Fboxes%2FCHA%2FCHA201506180.shtml&div=div_ChicagoWhiteSoxbatting"></script>
```

I've loaded it onto my page like this:

```
$.post(phpPage, {thisDate: dateOfGame}, function(returnedData) {
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( returnedData );
                //...some code here
                var str = obj["opposing_team_box_score"];
                var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
                newdiv.innerHTML = str;  
document.getElementById('opposing_boxscore').appendChild(newdiv);
});
```

The code gets rendered on the page all right, but it does not run:

```
<div id="opposing_boxscore">
                <div><script type="text/javascript" src="http://widgets.sports-reference.com/wg.fcgi?css=1&amp;site=br&amp;url=%2Fboxes%2FCHA%2FCHA201506180.shtml&amp;div=div_ChicagoWhiteSoxbatting"></script></div></div>
```

I believe this is because the script is loaded after the dom is loaded on the page.

Once the script is on the page, how do I get it to run? Is this even possible in jquery?

**********EDIT ***************************
I basically gave up on this method. It isn't what jquery was set up for. I sought and found an api that would provide the data I needed.

Comment: _"I believe this is because the script is loaded after the dom is loaded on the page.

Once the script is on the page, how do I get it to run? Is this even possible in jquery?"_ Where is `script` loaded ? What is `obj["opposing_team_box_score"]` ?

Comment: @guest271314: obj["opposing_team_box_score"] is being returned from a database call to the php page (from $.post). The script is loaded in the $.post call from the document ready function.

Comment: Is `obj["opposing_team_box_score"]` string  `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://widgets.sports-reference.com/wg.fcgi?css=1&site=br&url=%2Fboxes%2FCHA%2FCHA201506180.shtml&div=div_ChicagoWhiteSoxbatting"></script>
` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered this method won't work. I went on to use an API to get my data rather than try to store javascript code in a database field and make it run.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // do your stuff
});
```

The code inside runs when DOM is ready.

Comment: Yes, but I am loading the script dynamically within the document ready function already.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run external javascript using SCRIPT tag, you must insert this into HEAD tag ...

something like this

```
var head = document.head;
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'http://widgets.sports-reference.com/wg.fcgi?css=1&site=br&url=%2Fboxes%2FCHA%2FCHA201506180.shtml&div=div_ChicagoWhiteSoxbatting';

head.insertBefore(script,head.firstChild);
```

the good news is that "YES", you can load javascript dynamically using a script tag, the bad news is that the javascript you are trying to load is using document.write and It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.

Answer (score 0):

Note, "http://widgets.sports-reference.com/wg.fcgi?css=1&site=br&url=%2Fboxes%2FCH%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8BA%2FCHA201506180.shtml&div=div_ChicagoWhiteSoxbatting"

appear to return status code `500` `Internal Server Error` ?

---

Try substituting escaped closing forward slash at closing `<\/script>`.

```
$.post("/echo/json/", {
    json: JSON.stringify({
        "opposing_team_box_score": "<script>alert(123)<\/script>"
    })
}, function (returnedData) {
    var str = returnedData["opposing_team_box_score"];
    $("head").append(str);
}, "json");
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/99yk0o8L/1/

```js
var obj = {
 "opposing_team_box_score":"<script>alert(123)<\/script>"
};

var str = obj["opposing_team_box_score"];
$("head").append(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: That may work if you're hard coding onto the page. But it isn't working for when I pull code out of a database and try to make it run on the page.

Comment: @LauraNMS _"That may work if you're hard coding onto the page. But it isn't working for when I pull code out of a database and try to make it run on the page."_ See updated post. Perhaps issue server side ? Can include response from `phpPage` at Question ?